# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery20309916159505955875_1389540514154 is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, embedly

I am trying to put the embed.ly library in a google chrome extension. But when I run the following code

```
 $.embedly.defaults.key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
 $.embedly.extract('http://embed.ly').progress(function(data){alert(data.title)});
```

I get this error :
[image]

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not defined
JQuery is properly loaded and works normally, but it keeps loading with a new number (looks like a timestamp) attached to the Jquery name not defined in the error message.

When I click the error link, the extracted content seems to appear like so

```
jQuery20309916159505955875_1389540514154([{"provider_url": "http://embed.ly", "description": "Embedly delivers the ultra-fast, easy front-end tools developers need to build richer sites and apps.", "embeds": [], "safe": true, "provider_display": "embed.ly", "related": [], "favicon_url": "http://embed.ly/static/images/favicon.ico?v=0b3ad", "authors": [], "images": [{"caption": null, "url": "http://embed.ly/static/images/logos/logo_color.png?v=4b245", "height": 127, "width": 399, "colors": [{"color": [0, 0, 2], "weight": 0.80712890625}, {"color": [64, 196, 232], "weight": 0.1484375}, {"color": [246, 250, 251], "weight": 0.04443359375}], "entropy": 0.947677537089, "size": 23650}, {"caption": null, "url": "http://embed.ly/static/images/sketches/publishers-200.png?v=081c0", "height": 200, "width": 200, "colors": [{"color": [106, 209, 226], "weight": 0.8740234375}, {"color": [120, 80, 126], "weight": 0.1259765625}], "entropy": 2.4077095600808898, "size": 36127}], "cache_age": 70944, "lead": null, "language": "English", "original_url": "http://embed.ly", "url": "http://embed.ly/", "media": {}, "title": "Front-end developer tools for websites and apps | Embedly", "offset": null, "content": null, "entities": [], "favicon_colors": [{"color": [16, 172, 229], "weight": 0.450439453125}, {"color": [0, 4, 5], "weight": 0.435546875}, {"color": [242, 250, 252], "weight": 0.114013671875}], "keywords": [{"score": 17, "name": "apps"}, {"score": 15, "name": "websites"}, {"score": 14, "name": "embedding"}, {"score": 10, "name": "resize"}, {"score": 9, "name": "elements"}, {"score": 9, "name": "tool"}, {"score": 9, "name": "display"}, {"score": 8, "name": "articles"}, {"score": 7, "name": "smarter"}, {"score": 7, "name": "keywords"}], "published": null, "provider_name": "Embed", "type": "html"}])
```

Comment: It's JSONP, where jQuery adds a callback function with a random number. Exactly where and why is hard to tell without anything more than this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSONP.

You should not use JSONP in a content script, because JSONP works by inserting a `<script>` tag in the document, which calls a function with the result of the JSONP request. However, in Chrome's content script, the [execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) of this script is different from the page (where the `<script>` tag is injected). Consequently, you get an error about the function not being defined.

The right way to solve the problem is to declare the right permissions in your manifest file and use regular AJAX+JSON.

In your specific example, I see the following snippet [in the library you're using](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery/blob/6e2dea4888795753147d5b22e9cd93a2cdb40f64/jquery.embedly.js#L200-L212):

```
$.ajax({
    url: self.build(method, batch, options),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        ...
    }
});
```

Replace `dataType: 'jsonp'` with `datatype: 'json'` and your specific problem is solved.

If you cannot change the JSONP request to a regular AJAX request, I suggest to load `scriptTagContext.js` from https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext before your content scripts. `scriptTagContext.js` changes the behavior of `<script>` tags in a content script, such that these scripts always run in the same execution environment.

In all cases, you have to [declare the permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) to access the resource in the manifest file:

```
{
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "*://*.embed.ly/*"
    ],
    ...
}
```